# How to place a view horizontally center in a horizontal linear layout

Tags: android

I have a horizontal linear layout with 3 items inside of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FirstItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_microphone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ThirdItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the code, i sometimes hide the second and third item. I wish that my first item to be shown in the middle when the other two are hidden.

What can I do? Currently when I hide the 2nd and 3rd item, the first one still stays in the left. I could set layout_weight=1 on the first item but it doesn't appear correctly when 2 and 3 are Visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FirstItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_microphone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ThirdItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:gravity` or `android:layout_gravity` in your xml.

`android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content.

`android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the layout in its parent.

**Edit**

Use `android:gravity="center"` in your code it will work.

Comment: I tried a couple. Doesn't seem to work. Is it actually possible to horizontally center an item in a horizontal linear layout without filling the whole width?

Comment: Its best for you to try both, you will learn which to use and when. Here we guide people to solve their problems not actually solves their problem. After still you couldn't find your solution we are here to help :)

Comment: Is it actually possible to horizontally center an item in a horizontal linear layout without filling the whole width?

Comment: @user1017674 you hide the 2nd and 3rd item with GONE, right?

Comment: @user1017674 With `android:gravity="center"` in LinearLayout works.

Comment: WOW! I tried so many =/ except this. I ended up switching orientation at runtime lol. Could you post your answer and i'll accept it.